# Pushing a hash to an existing hash in Perl

Tags: perl, hash, push

I'm new to Perl, so you'll have to forgive my code.

I'm reading a file that tree structured (like xml, just not actually) and I want to `foreach` through the tree and if a certain "node" doesn't have a child node, I want to insert it. Simple enough.

Here's my code:

```
foreach $key ( @{$struct->{'transferBatch'}->{'callEventDetails'} } ) {

    foreach ( keys %{$key} ) {

        if ( $_ eq "mobileTerminatedCall" ) {

            if ( defined $key->{$_}->{'basicServiceUsedList'} ) {

                if ( defined $key->{$_}->{'basicServiceUsedList'}[0]->{'chargeInformationList'} ) {

                    if ( not defined $key->{$_}->{'basicServiceUsedList'}[0]->{'chargeInformationList'}[0]->{'CallTypeGroup'} ) {

                        $CallTypeGroup = {                          
                                "CallTypeLevel1:" => "0",
                            "CallTypeLevel2:" => "0",
                            "CallTypeLevel3:" => "0"

                        };                          

                        #Doesn't work! 
                        $key->{$_}->{'basicServiceUsedList'}[0]->{'chargeInformationList'}[0]{'CallTypeGroup'} =  $CallTypeGroup;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The iteration is working fine, but my `push` call fails saying it's not an ARRAY reference. I feel like I'm close, but I need that line to insert the `$CallTypeGroup` hash as a child to the current spot.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use references to store complex data structures as scalars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$key->{$_}->{'basicServiceUsedList'}[0]->{'chargeInformationList'}[0]
```

contains a reference to a hash, as created here (if not earlier):

```
if ( not defined
   $key->{$_}{basicServiceUsedList}[0]
      ->{chargeInformationList}[0]
         ->{CallTypeGroup} )
```

You did not indicate what data structure you want, so I'm not sure how we can help other than explain the message. I *think* you simply want to change that `if` to

```
if ( not defined
   $key->{$_}{basicServiceUsedList}[0]
      ->{chargeInformationList}[0] )
```

---

btw, you really should use variables to hold the intermediate references instead of having such long "names".

btw, I'm highly skeptical of all those hardcoded zero indexes.

Comment: The if statement works as intended, meaning that if the "CallTypeGroup" is not defined as a child, I need to add it. The zeros are place holder until I loop through, as of now I just wanted to get a working prototype.

Comment: I didn't say it didn't. I said I can't know if you don't tell us what data structure you want.

Comment: `$key->{$_}->{'basicServiceUsedList'}[0]->{'chargeInformationList'}[0]` is a hash, so I want to add `CallTypeGroup`, which is also a hash as a child.

Comment: @OnResolve, `push` adds to an *array*. Maybe `->{CallTypeGroup}` is missing from the `push`?

Comment: doh! well, that validates the error message I'm getting :-P.  So, I've updated my question to reflect adding to a hash, but although I receive no error message, the hash appears to be left unchanged.

Comment: Or maybe you want `key->{$_}{basicServiceUsedList}[0]{chargeInformationList}[0] = $CallTypeGroup;` (replacing the empty hash you created two lines earlier).

Comment: Add a hash *to what*. We know you want to add a hash, but to what? For the third time, if you want to go further, we need to know what data structure you want.

Comment: I thought I explained it already, but `$key->{$_}->{'basicServiceUsedList'}[0]->{'chargeInformationList'}[0]` is a hash, moreover it is embedded inside a hash itself (the tree concept I said in the question).  I simply want to add 1 key value pair to the `$key->{$_}->{'basicServiceUsedList'}[0]->{'chargeInformationList'}[0]` hash that already exists. The key value pair I want to add is the `CallTypeGroup`.  Keep in mind this is my first adventure with perl.